# Как правильно реализовать вызов модального окна в расширении?

Tags: javascript, html, chrome-extension, extension

У меня есть расширение, и мне нужно что бы по клику на кнопку на клавиатуре, допустим, `L` вызывалось модальное окно с какой-то надписью(простой `alert` не подойдет, т.к. окно нужно стилизовать). Но столкнулся с проблемой что не понимаю как именно это сделать: то ли нужно отдельные файлы с `html` и `css` делать или просто по нажатию на кнопку просто постоянно создавать `html` разметку с помощью  `js`. Кто уже работал с этим подскажите как это происходит? Функция вызова окна находиться в `content-script.js`.

Comment: Вас интересует именно перехват клавиши на произвольной веб-странице и покаж встроенного в страницу модального блока? Или достаточно будет настроить комбинацию клавишь на странице расширей (chrome://extensions/ , внизу странцы) и отображение popup-окна этого расширения?

Comment: @Deliaz именно показ окна на произвольной странице

Comment: @Deliaz то есть, что бы при нажатии на кнопку `L` окно вылетало по типу `alert`

Answer (score 5):

Наиболее правильным решением будет использовать [Shadow DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Shadow_DOM) для создания модального окна.

Это позводит изолировать встраеваемые стили от основного документа. 

Обратите внимание, что при обращении к созданному модальному окну необходимо использовать `shadowRoot` вместо `document`.

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Test",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "",
  "content_scripts": [{
    "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
    "js": ["content-script.js"],
    "run_at": "document_start"
  }]
}
```

**content-script.js**

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

    // создаем хост элемент для Shadow DOM
    const div = document.createElement('div'); 

    // создаем shadow DOM 
    const shadowRoot = div.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});

    // создаем модальное окно в shadow DOM 
    shadowRoot.innerHTML = '<h1 id="modal_form" style="display:none; border: 2px solid red;">Modal</h1>';

    // добавляем хост элемент в оригинальный DOM (document)
    document.body.appendChild(div);

    window.addEventListener('keydown', e => {
         if(e.keyCode === 76 ){ // "l" - key

            // показываем модальное окно
            // обратите внимание что здесь используется "shadowRoot"
            shadowRoot.querySelector('#modal_form').style.display = "block";
          }
    });
});
```

Comment: По каким-то причинам у меня данный вариант не сработал, ошибок нет как в коде, так и в консоли

Comment: @МаксимБуяков, попробовал еще раз, все получилось. Моя процедура: Cоздал два файла, скопировал вышеприведенный код -> Добавил экстеншн в браузер -> Открыл Google -> Нажал маленькую `l` -> Модальное окно появилось.

Comment: а как вы думаете, с чем может быть связано такое поведение?

Comment: @МаксимБуяков, не знаю. Вы перезагрузажи тестируемую вкладку после добавления расширения? Так же, возможно, модальное окно спрятано за другим элементом; попробуйте добавить `z-index`.

Comment: перезагружал, и `z-index` только что попробовал, ничего не помогло

Comment: Попробуйте отследить поведение content-script через devtools. Еще вариант: сделать `"run_at": "document_end"` и убрать событие `DOMContentLoaded` из cs.

Comment: не помогло, к сожалению